# ng-repeat populating only after window click - AngularJS & PouchDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pouchdb

I have the following function reading from a service:

```
var db = pouchService.db;
db.allDocs({startkey: 'move_', endkey: 'move_\uffff', include_docs: true})
.then(function (data) {
    $scope.recordlist = data;
    console.log($scope.recordlist);
});
```

Service:

```
angular.module('msfLogger').service('pouchService', PouchService);

function PouchService() {
  var self = this;
  self.db= new PouchDB('FleetDB');
};
```

On the front end, I'm trying to populate an ng-repeat from `$scope.recordlist`, but right now, when I load the page, the ng-repeat will be empty, and when I click anywhere on the page, it will get populated.

Also, when I add a new item in the DB, it will only show after page reload and click on window, not automatically.

```
<div class="row msf-row" ng-repeat="record in recordlist.rows">
    <div class="col-md-1">{{record.doc.time}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-1"><strong>{{record.doc.car}}</strong></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">{{record.doc.driver}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">{{record.doc.from}}</div> 

    ...
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you missing `$apply`

Comment: @Grundy, I have [angular-pouchdb](https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb) loaded in the doc. I thought it was solving that issue.

Comment: so can you provide working plunkr or jsfiddle? your code seems ok

Comment: do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: @Grundy nop! Is really weird, is like it only reads the ng-repeat on window click. $scope.recordlist exists on load (appears on console), but it won't appear on frontend. About jsfiddle, I'm in the middle of refactoring from LocalStorage to PouchDB, I don't see it possible right now, too much code and mess!

Comment: with localstorage all works fine? and problem only with Pouch?

Comment: Yes, LocalStorage is fine. I have a working version with LocalStorage only [here](http://cccctanger.com/fleet/). I'm changing to PouchDB because with LS after ~70 records in the same key, it starts to get slow...

Answer (score 1):

I think even if you have angular-pouchdb as a library, you need to inject it in the service, if not, you are using global PouchDB lib as normal and should be managing the `$scope.$apply` manually.

```
angular.module('msfLogger', ['pouchdb']).service('pouchService', PouchService);

function PouchService(pouchDB) {
  var self = this;
  self.db= pouchDB('FleetDB');
};
```

Comment: It's giving me `Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.4/ng/areq?p0=LoggerCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined`

Comment: @EricMitjans It looks like is something in your `LoggerCtrl`, not related to pouchdb.